# Проблема с заголовками

Tags: header, cookie

Интересная ситуация...
В firefox открываю новое приватное окно, смотрю чтобы кукисы были идеально чистыми.
Делаю запрос к site.com/wp-admin/
В инспекторе, в заголовках появляются куки одноименные с названием хостера

```
Cookies: "beget=begetok"
```

Как они туда попадают? Может ли хостер на лету отлавливать запрос и вставлять туда свои куки?
Дело в том, что без этих кук, ответ сервера 200 ОК с непонятными заголовками, а должен быть 302... как разобраться с этим я не знаю...может быть подскажете?

Answer (score 2):

Была такая же ситуация. Тебе хостер beget повесил фильтр или шаблон (как они его называют), скорее всего из-за скачка трафика на твой сайт, вызванного одной из причин:
 1. ддос-атака
 2. наплыв ботов
 3. наплыв реального трафика 
и как следствие перегрузки сервера по какому-либо параметру (БД или проц.)
Единственное, что меня напрягает, это то что они вешают этот фильтр без уведомления владельца сайта, что согласитесь не правильно, так как человек не знает о проблеме и не предпринимает никаких действий и сайт падает в поисковой выдаче со всеми вытекающими.
Меня постигла эта учесть даже на тарифе VIP. Так что пиши тикет в службу поддержки, пусть снимают свой шаблон.